# CakePhp 2.4 "Error: Shell class HelloShell could not be found." Paths mess?

Tags: shell, cakephp, console, cakephp-2.4

I have found several answers on that topic, but none did help me.

So here is the situation. I work on a ubuntu system and my default cakephp 2.4.4 installation is under:

```
/var/www/myproject/
  /gkm-be (this is my app)
  /lib/Cake
```

So all  paths here are default and the gkm_be app in general is working smoothly.

In my .bashrc I have the following setting:

```
PATH=$PATH:$HOME/bin
export PATH="$PATH:/var/www/myproject/lib/Cake/Console/"
```

When I open a new shell and go to the directory /var/www/myproject/gkm-be and type
    Console/cake 
I get the error
    bash: Console/cake: File or directory not found
after
    cd /var/www/myproject/gkm-be/Console/
if I enter cake then I get the core cake with following output

```
Welcome to CakePHP v2.4.4 Console
---------------------------------------------------------------
App : Console
Path: /var/www/myproject/gkm-be/Console/
---------------------------------------------------------------
Current Paths:

-app: Console
-working: /var/www/myproject/gkm-be/Console
-root: /var/www/myproject/gkm-be
-core: /var/www/myproject/lib

Changing Paths:

Your working path should be the same as your application path. To change your path use the '-app' param.
Example: -app relative/path/to/myapp or -app /absolute/path/to/myapp

Available Shells:

[CORE] acl, api, bake, command_list, console, i18n, schema, server, test, testsuite, upgrade
```

Note the paths for -app and -working

Not to mention of course that my HelloShell located under

```
/var/www/myproject/gkm-be/Console/Command/HelloShell.php
```

is neither listed nor can be called.

Were did I set a path wrong? Can anybody spot the mistake?

Calamity Jane

PS: The code from the shell:

```
class HelloShell extends AppShell
{

    public function main()
    {
        date_default_timezone_set('Europe/Berlin');
        $this->out('Hello world.');
    }

}
```

Comment: You need to always run the shells relative from your APP dir (/gkm-be) - and not Console! `/.../gkm-be>Console/cake hello`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

go to `/var/www/myproject/gkm-be` and run the command

```
../lib/Cake/Console/cake Hello
```

Comment: This produces tons of html output. I rather not include them here.

Comment: what should the Shell do? Are you getting html output that means the shell is not executed, or is it working and it's showing the output the Shell generates?

Comment: This produces tons of html output. I rather not include them here.

As far as I can see it is is that nagging error about the default timezone settings. To avoid it I explicitly set the timezone first thing in my shell. BUt if the shell isn't found, the line with the timezone setting cannot be found neither. 
After that I see an error about "Error: [CacheException] Cache engine long is not properly configured".

However it does not call my HelloShell.php and I don't see the typical shell output .

Comment: So far the shell just does the timezone setting and it's "hello world".

Comment: for the timezone, can you check Config/core.php, like 270 and make sure you have the line date_default_timezone_set('UTC'); uncommented? This would solve the timezone issue. It also says something about the cache engine not being ok, so it does run some cake functions

Comment: Thanks for the hint with the taimezone. That was still commented out. I thought I had that already activated.

Comment: are you still getting the message about Cache engine? can you tell us more about the errors? (not neccesarily paste the entire output)

Comment: Yes I still get them with the shell call:

2014-01-17 14:09:35 Error: [CacheException] Cache engine long is not properly configured.
Stack Trace:
#0 /var/www/sangius-backend/lib/Cake/Cache/Cache.php(151): Cache::_buildEngine('long')
#1 /var/www/sangius-backend/gkm-be/Config/bootstrap.php(51): Cache::config('long', Array)
#2 ...
#9 {main}

The Cache "long" is configured in the app's bootstrap.php:

Cache::config(
    'long', array(
    'engine' => 'File',
    'duration' => '+26 hours',
    'path' => CACHE.'long'.DS,
    'probability' => 100,
    'prefix' => 'cake_long_',
    )
);

Weird.

Comment: oh how stupid.... looks like it was the access (write) rights to the cache directrory.
Oh blimey....

Comment: And behold: Now it works with your suggested call! Thank you for your help!